# Tag helper for collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Let's say I have a view-models like this:

```
public class AbonentViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<AbonentCertificate> Certificates { get; set; }
}

public class AbonentCertificate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a tag helper which could show list of `Certificates` using custom html like this:

```
<multi-list asp-for="Certificates">
    <div class="list-item">
       <input asp-for="Name" />
       <input asp-for="FileName" />
    </div>
</multi-list>
```

Html inside th multi-list element would be repeated for each certificate object with appropriate values set.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not run a foreach loop instead? In don't see the reason for a TagHelper

Comment: A simple `foreach(var cartificate in certificates){ .. your html here}` is just as effective.